# Find an integrating factor for getting an exact differential

Tags: real-analysis

Given the equation $\delta Q = \frac{5}{2}RdT -\frac{RT}{p}dp$ I need to find an integrating factor $g(p,T)$ such that $dY = g(p,T)\delta Q $ will be an exact differential. I was first trying by integrating the terms $g(p,T)\frac{5}{2}R$ in respect to $T$ and/or $-g(p,T)\frac{RT}{p}$ in respect to $p$. I also further assumed that $g(p,T)=g(p).$ But maybe I shouldn't.

Can you help me out how to find $g(p,T) ?$

Thanks.

Comment: Yup, maybe you shouldn’t, since it didn’t work. What’s your next thing to try?

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Why did you try a function of $p$ only?

Comment: For simplicity reasons. The function $g(p)$ must then satisfy the condition $\frac{5}{2}g(p)RT = -RT\int \frac{g(p)}{p}dp.$ This is equivalent to $\frac{5}{2}g'(p) = -\frac{g(p)}{p}.$ Separation of variables and integration leads to $g(p) = \frac{K}{p^{2/5}}.$ We may set $K=1$ and thus we get $Y(p,T) = \frac{5}{2}\frac{RT}{p^{2/5}}.$ Other then expected, $Y$ is not a homogeneous function of 1 or maybe 0 degree (Y is a state variable in thermodynamics). Thus, there must be a mistake. I do not see where the error is.

Comment: Thermodynamic state variables do not need to be of degree 1 or 0 in pressure or temperature. I suggest multiplying through by $\frac {2p}R$ first, then looking at the resulting differential and deciding what other factor multiplied through might give this result upon differentiating a function.

Comment: Thanks. Is my procedure wrong ? When I use the same procedure based on your suggestion, $g(p) = \frac{2p}{R},$ I do not get a viable result. I simply get $pT=0.$ What I do is to integrate the first term in respect to $T$ and then set this equal to the integral of the second term.

Comment: I’ve done everything to get you to open your mind. Your choice of “simplicity” failed. Why not try another obvious simplicity?

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your comment. Is there a failure in the method of finding the function $g(p,T)$ that I am using independent of the choice of setting $g(p,T) = g(p)$ or simply keeping $g(p,T) ?$